# TStream.Position compared to TStream.Seek

Tags: delphi

To move the "current byte" pointer in TStream class we can use property Position (e.g. MyStream.Position := 0) or using Seek method (e.g. MyStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning). The question is, which one is more efficient (aka faster)? (I don't have the source, so I could not check it myself).

So far I always use Seek in positioning that said pointer.

Comment: @Marjan and kyndigs: there is a post on Synapse change log page (http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/ChangeLog.html) that intrigued me, it says: "Using TStream.Position instead of TStream.Seek. Better compatibility with large streams." (under ftpsend change)

Comment: Intriguing yes. Could have something to do with Position always using the 64-bit version of Seek first as mentioned in @Uwe's answer.

Comment: Stream.Seek(iPos, soFromCurrent) is equivalent to Stream.Position:= Stream.Position+ iPos;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `TStream.Seek` is an overloaded function handling 32-Bit or 64-Bit values, it depends on the current stream implementation, which might be the better choice.

For instance `TCustomMemoryStream`  implements the 32-Bit version of `Seek()`. When you set `Position` on that stream this will first call the 64-Bit version, which casts the value to a Longint while calling the 32-Bit version. (This will probably change with a 64-Bit version of Delphi!)

On the other hand a `THandleStream` implements the 64-Bit version of `Seek()`. When you call `Seek()` with a 32-Bit value you end up in a quite nasty mechanism calling the 64-Bit version.

My personal advice would be to set `Position`. At least it will be the better choice in the future.

Comment: The problem is I still can not see the point using Position is more recommended than using Seek, since setter Position is in the end simply calling Seek.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. I just took a peek to D7 vcl source and inspected the code completion hint on D2010, now I can see your point.  Now I have to change my coding behavior...

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the function call overhead to the Position property setter, there is no difference as setting the Position property calls Seek with the given value and starting at the beginning.:

```
procedure TStream.SetPosition(const Pos: Int64);
begin
  Seek(Pos, soBeginning);
end;
```

Comment: Sigh, so actually there is no difference (beside the call overhead).. So I guess I'll stick with seek to save that call overhead.. :)

Comment: This implementation of SetPosition will always call the 64-Bit version of seek, while a direct call to Seek might end up in the 32-Bit version. See my answer for the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any big performance between them.

```
Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning)
```

This can take different parameters, so you can seek from the start, current position or end of stream.

```
Stream.Position
```

This gets or sets the absolute position of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be a reference for readers: Seek is deprecated in Delphi/Rad Studio XE4, so you should use TStream.Position instead of Seek.

Comment: I noticed that but could not find the runtime library code where the deprecated keyword was actually used. Did you?

Comment: @dummzeuch Only the function Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: Word) is marked deprecated in unit System.Classes. The function Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin) is still valid. The difference is the 2nd Origin parameter! You should use the TSeekOrigin enum version. Best, denim

Comment: The following is from C++Builder 10.1 Berlin: "Warning: Using these constants may generate unwanted/wrong code, because an overloaded seek method will be used, which uses offest : longint, thus limiting seekrange to 2GB." So always check your TStream implementation used before deciding, e.g. THandleStream should be safe.

Comment: IMO, continuing to use Seek is just a piece of code which has "I want to be a bug" written all over it.

Comment: Not an answer, and factually incorrect. Seek is not deprecated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, There are 3 overloaded methods of Seek. One of them is deprecated, the one were the second argument "Origin" is a Word instead of a TSeekOrigin. So if everyone is using soBeginning instead of soFromBeginning the problem should be solved

Comment: @rvheddeg Indeed. Call the others.

Comment: The 3rd overload was [added as a bug fix to address errors in user code](https://www.thedelphigeek.com/2013/10/tstreamadapterseek-apology.html), that is why it is `deprecated` - well behaved code won't call it, but it "does the right thing" if it does get called.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in one of the comments, there are 3 overloaded methods of Seek. One of them is deprecated, the one were the second argument "Origin" is a Word instead of a TSeekOrigin.

TSeekOrigin = (soBeginning, soCurrent, soEnd);

So if everyone is using TSeekOrigin this problem should be solved.

Better would of course be just to set the position, like the accepted solution...

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same. You should use the option that is more legible.