# Error with IStream.Seek()

Tags: ole, seek, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a very old piece of code to handle Excel files in Delphi 5, which I adapted to work with Delphi 2005, which I used professionally until 2010. Since then, there was no reasonable free version of Delphi. Therefore, it is only now that using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo I would like to adapt it once again.

A problem that I was not able to solve is related to the use of `OleStream.Seek(...)` in the function given below, where I get a fatal error with all expressions in `OleCheck(...)`.

Also, I didn't find any hint on a similar problem searching for the function `OleStream.Seek(...)` on the Internet.

The code is the following

```
function Streamseek(offset : longint; origin: word):string;
var   
  Pos : longInt ; //  Pos: largeint;
begin
  if FBIFFVersion > biff4 then begin
    case Origin of
      soFromBeginning:
        OleCheck(OStream.Seek(Offset,STREAM_SEEK_SET,Pos));  //  ENUM:  set =0
      soFromCurrent:
        OleCheck(OStream.Seek(Offset,STREAM_SEEK_CUR,Pos));        /// 1 cur
      soFromEnd:
        OleCheck(OStream.Seek(Offset,STREAM_SEEK_END,Pos));        //    2      end
    end;
```

Of course, it is just one function in a much bigger program, which is not relevant here.

My problem is: I searched for 
`OStream.Seek(Offset,STREAM_SEEK_SET,Pos)` on the Internet, but I could only find `OleStream.seek(offset : longint; origin: word):string;` except for one webpage, but there the same types were used.

[Working with IStream in Delphi](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2009/01/working-with-istream-in-delphi.html)

So, I wonder what parameter types need to be used.

In the German version of Delphi 10.2.3, I get the error:

> [dcc32 Fehler] line(878): E2033 Die Typen der tatsächlichen und formalen Var-Parameter müssen übereinstimmen

In English:

> The types of the real and the formal var parameters must be the same.

It is clear that `largeint` is not a modern parameter type, and I only see the possibility that, instead of `Integer`, `LongInt`, `Int64` or else is needed since the number of parameters should be OK.

`LongInt` instead of `Integer` for `offset` does not work, `Longint` instead of `LargeInt` does not work for `pos`.

Has anyone an idea what might be the reason for the error? What are the required types of this function in Delphi 10.2.3?

Comment: Have you tried simply looking at the actual declaration of `Seek()`? That will tell you exactly which types to use. CTRL-LClick on `Seek()` in the code editor, or RClick on it and choose "Find Declaration".

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882212/tstream-position-compared-to-tstream-seek?

Comment: Hello,off course it was my first idea to search for the declaration ... but only in the file and myself. So as suggested I used the command find declaration and I found it. Thanks very much.. Sorry for this very easy question but it is my first day after 10 years with Delphi and I never had such a problem before...                     By the way it was largeUint...